# Does TrueVault support oAuth?

Tags: oauth, parse-platform, truevault

Does TrueVault have oAuth built into it? Can I show a button on my webapp that says "Login via TrueVault"? I'm trying to add third party auth to Parse.

https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth for TrueVault is currently in closed beta. We will be announcing its release soon. Stay tuned!

Comment: Thanks Dan, How do you recommend passing the credentials over the wire with the current Basic Auth support? We will be using Javascript on the front end, angularJS to be precise.

Comment: @smaira: Until OAuth is released, we recommend you retrieve your API Key prior to making an API call to TrueVault. This prevents the need to store your TrueVault API key in plaintext.

Comment: @Jason but as per the docs the recommended way for normal users is via ACCESS_TOKEN, right? My worry was sending the username/password with Basic Auth to the Login Api. How secure is that? Since we're dealing with HIPAA compliance and the username might also contain PHI (name,email etc) we want to make sure its secure end to end. Please take a look at this post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https